# SQL Server adding access for user to create table

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I own a new DB and I have multiple schemas setup and users have different group accesses to ensure they can only edit the schemas they need access to.  Recently I gave alter and create access to a user for a schema and the user still can't insert a table.  I do my user maintenance through SSMS.  What am I doing wrong?  Would I be better off to execute a SQL script versus using the GUI in SSMS?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

The steps I used to grant access initially was as follows, I have a database role permission with the Schema on the securables tab, I then checked the boxes next to Alter, Control, Create, Delete, Execute, Insert, Select, and Update.  Then I added users to this DB Role.  The users can select but not insert/create a table.

The SQL script the user tried is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Database.Schema.test_table (
oid numeric PRIMARY KEY
,columnEX numeric NOT NULL
,columnEX2 numeric
);
```

The error message received was as follows:

CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'database'.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would add 1) exactly what you did to grant access, 2) exactly what statement(s) the user is trying to execute, 3) what the exact error is.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just edited the question and added that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a table a user requires *both* CREATE TABLE permission in the database and ALTER on the target schema.

And it's a *strong* security best practice to make the user (or group) the owner of the target schema, rather than granting them ALTER or CONTROL on a schema owned by another user.  If you grant a user the rights to ALTER or CONTROL a schema owned by a privileged user (like dbo), then they can use ownership chains to access any object in any schema owned by that privileged user.

Comment: When I try to create a DB Role to grant access at the database level to create a table or view, once I add the database and those permissions to the securables section and click OK, when I come back, that information is gone.....?

Comment: Might be SSMS wierdness.  sys.database_permissions is the ground truth.